# Asterisk inbound/outbound SIP trunk with Twilio

Tags: voip, asterisk, twilio

I'm trying to use Twilio as my SIP trunk for an Asterisk install. I can get Google Voice to work, but can't get Twilio to work. Here are the SIP trunk settings. What am I missing?

```
Outgoing Settings --

Trunk name: Twilio-Out<br
PEER Details:<br
username=\*\*\*username\*\*\*<br
type=peer<br
secret=\*\*\*password\*\*\*<br
context=from-trunk<br
host=\*\*\*name\*\*\*.sip.twilio.com

Incoming Settings --

USER Context: Twilio-In<br
USER Details:<br
type=user<br
context=from-trunk<br
secret=\*\*\*password\*\*\*<br

Registration --

Register String: [empty]
```

Comment: What is config on asterisk side? What is dialplan? What say sip debug on asterisk?

Comment: Asterisk Config: NAT, Static IP, using ulaw codec. Everything else is default, including the dialplan. I've only got one out route, so everything should be using it. Here's the log: http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=VecBq

Comment: This log show that you have read some book about freepbx config. There are no any dialling in this log. So outbound routes and/or trunks not set.

Comment: Didn't use a book, but I still need help. I've got the trunk set up, but for some reason, asterisk isn't using it. That's where I need help.

Comment: You need setup outbound routes. Sorry, this is questions site, for full-featured manual google in internet.

Answer (score 0):

(If you have access to the asterisk configuration file)

Try adding following section in the `sip.conf` file

```
register => NNNN@XXXX.sip.us1.twilio.com:YYYY:XXXX.sip.us1.twilio.com:5060

[phone]
host=XXXX.sip.us1.twilio.com
secret=YYYY
defaultuser=NNNN
fromuser=NNNN
fromdomain=XXXX.sip.us1.twilio.com
insecure=port,invite
type=peer
allow=gsm,ulaw,alaw
context=KKKK
tos_sip=cs3
tos_audio=ef
```

Here,
XXXX is subaccount/acccount name on the twilio. If you are not usa, update the twilio host and domain server near your location.
YYYY is the password.
NNNN is credential you created in twilio under the subaccount.
KKKK is the name of the dialplan section which you want to get executed when you get incoming calls.

Also, you need to define the dialplan in the `extensions.conf` file.